# Must the number of inserted column be the same as that of the target tables?

Tags: dolphindb

When I insert data, must the number of inserted column be the same as that of the target tables?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [upsert!()](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/u/upsert!.html) function, the inserted column must be consistent with structure of the target table.
If you use the [tableInsert()](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/t/tableInsert.html) function, you can insert part columns by passing into the second parameter a dictionary. But it is applied to the in-memory tables.